# run function with all possibilities resulted from other function

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof

I have two predicates:

```
foo(Y,X)
bar(Y,Z)
```

After running foo, How can I run bar with all possibilities of Y ?

example:

```
foo(Y, key) % all possibilities of Y => chat 
            %                           faq 
            %                           about
            %                           search
```

How can I run bar with these all possibilities ?

```
bar(chat, Z)
bar(faq, Z)
bar(about, Z)
bar(serach, Z)
```

And then store all the results of `Z` in a list `Zs`?

Comment: you can put all possible values of `Y` in a list, then write the predicate `bar` accordingly.

Comment: @FlopCoder can you supply a sample code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
allZs(X, Zs) :-
    setof(Y, foo(Y, X), Ys),
    maplist(bar, Ys, Zs).
```

related SWI-Prolog man pages: [Finding all Solutions to a Goal](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions) and [library apply](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=apply)

Note: usually in Prolog the convention is to put intput arguments before output ones - in your first predicate that'd mean `foo(X, Y)` instead of `foo(Y, X)`. Plus here it'd outline the transitivity: `foo(X, Y), bar(Y, Z).`.

Comment: Actually, I have store undirected graph over using foo. Ex: foo (x,y) means x and y are connected to each other. I am finding a way from neighbour of y to target. For this reason, I have write foo (Y,X ).

Comment: Well yeah it was a sidenote, it happens that an inversed order is justified.

Answer (score 2):

foo/2 and bar/2 are already in *join*, and after each run of foo/2 bar/2 will be tried.

Maybe you are looking for `forall(foo(Y,X), bar(Y,Z))`, that run *all* possibilities of foo/2, *and* then bar/2. I.e. is required that bar/2 doesn't fail.

To understand the behaviour of forall/2, as well as other *all solutions* builtins, like setof/3, can be useful test with very simple builtins, with well known behaviour:

```
?- forall(member(X,[f,o,o]),(member(Y,[b,a,r]),writeln(X-Y))).
f-b
o-b
o-b
true.
```

You can see that the complete solution search of forall applies to its first argument, not the second.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
barOnList([], []).
barOnList([Y|Ys], [Z|Zs]) :- bar(Y, Z), barOnList(Ys, Zs).
```

Comment: `maplist/3` would do the trick too, and if it's not provided in the implementation you use, several ones are proposed here on SO.

Comment: But, foo in not return a list.It returns only one value. Ex: foo(Y,key) return chat then I press a to show all possibilities. Afterwards, faq, about, search are also seen in terminal.