# map function result to another

Tags: prolog

After I have seen [these question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10844782/1428237), I have tried to solve below problem. But I could not solve it. Can anyone help me ?

```
predefined :

   foo( X, Y )        bar( Y, Z )
        ^  ^               ^  ^
      all of them is atomic, that is they only return or take one value at a time

   sample example:

      foo(john, brad).
      bar(john, marry).

      foo( Y, brad)   

      Y = john   % after pressing a, all possibilities will be seen at terminal

      bar(Y, Z )

      Z = marry  % after pressing a, all possibilities will be seen at terminal

   %..................
```

For these case how can I run bar with all possibilities of Y, resulted after eash run of foo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `bar/2` is a predicate that results in certain side effects, such as input-output, being produced, then that is what backtracking is for.

You just say:

```
   ?- foo(X,Y),bar(Y,Z).
```

And get all the possibilities, pressing `a` or `;` depending on your implementation.

Alternatively, you can write

```
   ?- foo(X,Y),bar(Y,Z),write(bar(Y,Z)),nl,fail.
```

On the other hand, if you need to check if there is a `bar(Y,Z)` pair for every `Y` that satisfies `foo(X,Y)`, than you can use Prolog `forall/2` facility. For instance, the following goal will be true only if for every `Y` that results from foo(X,Y), there exists a `Z` that satisfies `bar(Y,Z)`.

```
   ?- forall(foo(X,Y),bar(Y,Z)).
```

**Examples**

Given the following facts

```
foo(a,b).
foo(a,c).
bar(c,x).
bar(c,y).
```

With the first goal you get

```
?- foo(X,Y),bar(Y,Z),write(bar(Y,Z)),nl,fail.
bar(c,x)
bar(c,y)
false.
```

With the second goal:

```
?- forall(foo(X,Y),bar(Y,Z)).
false.
```

Since the goal `bar(b,Z).` fails.